# use another column for grouping ,incase there is two rows with max number in the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, pandas-groupby

I have a [csv file that contains information about games played in the last 5 decades](https://www.kaggle.com/spn007/la-liga-dataset). I am going to find the winning team in each season for the past years.  so I should check points column but in case there are two teams with the same max points, I should check goal_difference.

```
df3=pd.DataFrame(df_laliga.groupby('season')[['points']].max(axis=1).reset_index())
result=pd.merge(df3,df_laliga,how='inner',on=['points','season'])
result=result[['season','club']].set_index('season')
del result.index.name
```

the result is in this format

[image]

In season 2006-07 two teams have the same points and there are two teams. I tried it in the way below but the problem didn't give me the right result.

```
df3=pd.DataFrame(df_laliga.groupby('season')[['points','goal_difference']].max(axis=1).reset_index())
```

raw data:

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you provide the original (raw) data ?

Comment: Sure.I put some pictures of table and link to data in question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this can be done easily using pandasql. You can do something like this.

```
!pip install pandasql

import pandasql

query = """
        SELECT
          season,
          club
        FROM
          (SELECT
            season,
            club,
            points,
            goal_difference
          FROM
            df_laliga
          ORDER BY
            season,
            points,
            goal_difference)
        GROUP BY
          season
        """

result = pandasql.sqldf(query)

result
```

Comment: @kosarafrooshe ohh i think i have typo in team column, it should be club, i edited it, you can try it again. Make sure your raw data is in `df_laliga` variable.

Comment: yes I know that and changed it but again there was an error.

Comment: I fixed the error but the problem is that the result is not right and the chosen club is not the one that wins the season